# How To Get The TotalPage of a store?

Tags: extjs4

In My Program I'am Using Grid Pagination. In a particular situvation I need the totalPage

count of a store.Any Way To Get it?

Please Help Me....

Answer (score 3):

Your server should send back the total number of records, something like this:

```
{
 success:true,
 total:999,
 records:[
  {
   id:1,
   name:'Arundev PV'
  }
 ]
}
```

then you can use store.getTotalCount() to get that value.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getTotalCount

you can customize the name of the "total" property with

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-totalProperty

Comment: Is there any way to create 'total' in the JSON response by passing it as a parameter from the store?